# How to access the website via IP address without SSL error

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, pki, san

When I'm accessing any host via IP address, it is showing SSL error.

`Example.com` => `192.168.1.1` (IP address)

Suppose if I want to access `https://example.com`, it works fine.
If on the other hand, accessing the hosts by its IP address like `https://192.168.1.1`, it shows SSL Error.

Is there any configuration missing here. Do I need to add the IP address in SAN configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access a web site by IP address you need to first configure your web server to actually provide this web site on this IP address and then you have to include the IP address as SAN into the certificate served at this IP address. Note that there are different types of SAN: DNSName and IPAddress. The correct type would be IPAddress but some clients actually wrongly expect type DNSName - so you better add the IP address with both SAN types.

Comment: Thanks, but suppose if I don't want to add IP address to SAN. Will it be possible for an attacker to conduct the man in the middle attack?

Comment: @AdityaBali: If you don't add the IP to the SAN then you will face an SSL error. The same kind of error you'll face if a man in the middle attack is going on. Most users will not be able to distinguish if this as error which can be ignored or if this is an error which is caused by an attack.